# Efficient object initialization

Tags: java, performance, initialization

I am creating a mock Twitter project which loads user data from a somewhat large text file containing ~3.6 million lines formatted like this:

```
0 12
0 32
1 9
1 54
2 33
etc...
```

The first string token is the `userId` and the second is the `followId`.

The first half of this helper method takes in the current user's ID, checks to see if it exists and creates a new user if necessary. After that, the `followId` is added to this new or existing user's following list of type `ArrayList<Integer>`.

With ~3.6 million lines to read, this doesn't take long (9868 ms).

Now the second half creates or finds the followed user (`followId`) and adds the `userId` to their *followers* list, but this additional code extends the amount of time to read the file exponentially (172744 ms).

I tried using the same `TwitterUser` object throughout the method. All of the adding methods (`follow`, `addFollower`) are simple `ArrayList.add()` methods. Is there anything I can do to make this method more efficient?

**Please note:** While this is school-related, I'm not asking for an answer to my solution. My professor permitted this slow object initialization, but I'd like to understand how I can make it faster.

```
private Map<Integer, TwitterUser> twitterUsers = new HashMap<Integer, TwitterUser>();

private void AddUser(int userId, int followId){
    TwitterUser user = getUser(userId);
    if (user == null){
        user = new TwitterUser(userId);
        user.follow(followId);
        twitterUsers.putIfAbsent(userId, user);
    } else{
        user.follow(followId);
    }
    //adding the code below, slows the whole process enormously
    user = getUser(followId);
    if (user == null){                     
        user = new TwitterUser(followId);
        user.addFollower(userId); 
        twitterUsers.putIfAbsent(followId, user);
    } else{
        user.addFollower(userId);
    }
}

private TwitterUser getUser(int id){
    if (twitterUsers.isEmpty()) return null;
    return twitterUsers.get(id);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to check if `twitterUsers.isEmpty()` in `#getUser`, `Map#get` returns `null` if the specified key is not found. This won't substantially reduce runtime but it is redundant. Could you also post the  `TwitterUser#follow` and `TwitterUser#addFollower` code?

Comment: well if `putIfAbsent` is a HashMap method and `follow` is simply: 1.) check if !ArrayList.contains(int) ... 2.) ArrayList.add(int) @JonnyHenly

Comment: good point about the `isEmpty()` check.. silly of me

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize `putIfAbsent` was a method of `HashMap`. Have you considered using another `HashMap` instead of an `ArrayList`, since the lookup time for an `ArrayList` is linear?

Comment: @JonnyHenly oh jeez, that makes sense. I will certainly look into that!

Comment: @JonnyHenly hey so I tried using a HashSet in place of the ArrayList and it appears to be a huge CPU hog.

Comment: @JonnyHenly i will add that it took < 15 seconds to load all the data when I wasn't doing my `contains` check so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If `putIfAbsent(int, User)` does what you would expect it to do, that is: *checking if it's there before inserting*, why do you use it within an `if` block whose condition already checks if the user is there?

In other words, if fetching a user returned a `null` value you can safely assume that the user was not there.

Now I'm not too sure about the internal workings of the `*putIfAbsent*` method (probably it would loop through the set of the keys in the map), but intuitively I would expect a normal `put(int, User)` to perform better, even more with a map that gets as large as yours as the input file gets scanned through.

Therefore I would suggest to try something like:

```
user = getUser(followId);
if (user == null){                     
    user = new TwitterUser(followId);
    user.addFollower(userId); 
    twitterUsers.put(followId, user);
 } else{
    user.addFollower(userId);
 }
```

which would apply to the first half as well.